# How to check if optional parameter defined

Tags: typescript

This is the way i'm using to check if body property has been provided to the function.

is there any simpler way to do it in TypeScript?

```
httpAPI<T>(httpMethod: HttpMethod, url: string, optional?: { params?: HttpParams, body?: any, isUseCache?:boolean }): Observable<T> 
{

    const body: any = optional === undefined || optional.body === undefined ? undefined : optional.body;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign a default empty object return `{}`. Then use shortcut to get `body`.

```
interface IOptional = { 
  params?: HttpParams, 
  body?: any, 
  isUseCache?:boolean 
};

httpAPI<T>(httpMethod: HttpMethod, url: string, optional?: IOptional = {}): Observable<T> 
{
  const { body } = optional;
}
```

You can also use `lodash get` or `lodash fp getOr` to achieve the same purpose.

Comment: Can you explain what is "{ body }" mean in the line: const { body } = optional; ?